# Rails how to group_by data with conditions?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, group-by

I have two tables , book:

```
book:
id
book_name
brand_id

belongs_to :brand, foreign_key: "brand_id"
```

and brand:

```
brand:
id
brand_name

has_many :books
```

I want to group data from book and get results like following:

```
id brand_name count
1     b1        20
2     b2        32
```

and display on view, use params to get values and insert into collection_select like:

```
<%= collection_select('', :brand_id, @brands , @brands.id, @brands.name + '(' + @brands.count + ')'  , {:prompt => 'please select!'} ) %><br>
```

I want the dropdown list looks like :

b1(20)
b2(32)

how can I do that?
I tried @brands = Book.group(:brand_id).count
but it's only shows:

```
'1':20
'2':32
```

I don't know how to get value via params, and there is no brand_name, please give me some suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can try this way. Just sure with your model name and table name in query. It returns you a active record array then you can manage in according to your collection select hash:

```
brands = Book.joins(:brand).select("brands.id as id, brands.name as brand_name,count(*) as count").group(:brand_id)
```

You can create your required array by

```
@brands = brands.collect{|o| ["#{o.brand_name}(#{o.count})",o.id]}
```

After that you can passed this array to select tag as:

```
<%= select_tag  'brand_id' , options_for_select(@brands) %>
```

Comment: no need to convert to json it. editing it. actually m tested it on rails console so for viewing that records i have used as_json converter. there is no meaning here. without it just showing active records array.

Comment: I mean `@brands = (...).to_json` line

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions to your problem is:

```
@brands = Brand.joins(:books).select("brands.id, brands.name, COUNT(books.id) as cnt").group("brands.id, brands.brand_name")
```

Now you can convert it to collection, which you can be used by [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) helper:

```
collection = @brands.map{|b| [ "#{b.name} (#{b.cnt})", b.id ] }
```

and use it in your form:

```
select 'book', 'brand_id', collection
```